# After a div animate still behind other div

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, width, mouseenter

Situation:
I have 3 div's
|left|center|right|
I have 3 other divs inside left and 3 other inside right.
When I pass in any of this 6 divs, they increase width.
The right side is ok, but the left side, when it grows, is still behind the center div.

Is more easy too see:
Pass the mouse over left menu, and you still see the text in the center div. This behavior do not happens on the right side.

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="menu_left">
            <div class="item_left"> </div>
            <div class="item_left"> </div>
            <div class="item_left"> </div>
        </div>

        <div class="central">XXXXXXXX XXXXXXX</div>

        <div class="menu_right">
            <div class="item_right"> </div>
            <div class="item_right"> </div>
            <div class="item_right"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    //$("div").fadeIn(3500);

    $(".item_left").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({ width: "240px"}, 350);

    });
    $(".item_left").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({ width: "100px" }, 350);
    });
    $(".item_right").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).animate({ width: "240px"}, 350);
    });
    $(".item_right").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).animate({ width: "100px" }, 350)
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lcssanches/E7B3t/1/

**EDIT:**

Left menu: I want avoid this
[image: left_menu]

Right menu: correct! 
[image: roght_menu]

Comment: does for me.  u sure ur original is correct?  also, u might want to consider going to css3 when u can.  less lines.  better performance.  some stuff still doesn't work well like using `auto` `height`s and `width`s

Comment: ok, I will look more about css3. but see the images pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your CSS code below, it appears you're wanting the left/right items to cover the central `div`, only your mistake is a spelling one - `postion:` should be `position:`

```
div.menu_left,div.menu_right{
  postion: relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/E7B3t/3/